# C++ How to read in a text file and reverse the lines so it reads from bottom up

Tags: c++

Please help I'm new to C++

Using stacks Implementation

I should read a sample text file containing:

```
text file
begining to end
return text
```

And return a text file reading:

```
return text
begining to end
test file
```

This is the sample code to test the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "stack1.h"
using namespace std

void reverse (ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile);  //function prototype

int main () {

ifstream infile;  // declaring a file for input
ofstream outfile; // declaring a file for output
infile.open ("c:\\myInputFile.txt");  

 if (!infile)  { cout << "File could not be opened.  Program terminated." << endl;
           return 1;    // terminates program
         }
 outfile.open ("c:\\myOutfile.txt");
 reverse (infile, outfile);
 infile.close();
outfile.close();
 return 0;
 }

void reverse (ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile) {
 string s;
 stack<string> mystack;

 getline(infile, s); // try to read a line of text from the file
 while (!infile) { // while not end of file
  mystack.push(s);
  getline(infile, s); // try to read another line
  }
 while (! mystack.isEmpty() ) {
  s = mystack.pop();
  outfile << s << endl; // write s to the outfile
  }
 }
```

Comment: @BillyONeal. Thanks, can't edit yet.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
//open infile in and outfile out.
std::stack<std::string> lines;
std::string temp;
while(std::getline(in, temp)) lines.push(temp);
while(!lines.empty()) outfile << lines.pop() << std::endl;
```

I'm unsure exactly what your question is here though.

Edit: changed `push_back()` and `pop_back` to `push()` and `pop()` respectively (because those are what `std::stack` provides).

Comment: I agree what is your question. Seems the code you have already should work you just need to pop the stack at the end and display all it's contents to view the file in reverse.

Comment: This did not compile with VS2008. `lines.pop()` returns `void` as per MSDN. I had to use `lines.top()`.

Comment: @Agnel: Doh! Used to using plain Vectors because stack is just an adaptor in top of vector. @Jerry: Thanks for fixing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `!`

```
while (infile) { // while not end of file
```

You could use `std::stack` instead of whatever is in `"stack1.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this you can directly store it without using stack.I think it should work.

```
int checkstatus(ifstream &in)
{
ios::iostate i;
i = in.rdstate();
if(i & ios::eofbit)
return 0;//cout << "EOF encountered\n";
else if(i & ios::failbit)
return 0;//cout<<"Non-Fatal I/O error\n";
else if(i & ios::badbit)
return 0;//cout<<"Fatal I/O error\n";

return 1;
}


int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("test.txt");
    char c;
    in.seekg(0,ios::end);
        while(checkstatus(in) != 0)
        {
            in.seekg(-1,ios::cur);
            in.get(c);
            in.seekg(-1,ios::cur);
            if(checkstatus(in) == 0)
            break;
            cout<<c;

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works by seeking every character from EOF. Don't have to replicate any data this way using stack or vector.